# How to implement CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK in my application?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bitmask, change-tracking

When working with [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#using-column-tracking) in SQL Server, you're supposed to use `CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK` to determine which column was changed when dealing with updates. For example, like so:

```
DECLARE @last_synchronization_version bigint = ...;
DECLARE @column_id int = ...;

-- The statement below returns 1 if the specified column (@column_id) was changed, otherwise 0.

SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK(@column_id, SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS)
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.MyTable, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT
```

I wonder, is there a way to implement `CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK` myself, so I can work with the value of `SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS` in my application without having to know beforehand which columns my application is interested in when executing the query?

For example, when I only change the value of the column with ID `11`, the value of `SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS` is `0x000000000B000000`.

[image]

How can I programmatically determine that this mask contains the information that column 11 was changed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674192/sql-server-how-to-list-changed-columns-with-change-tracking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043710/sql-change-tracking-sys-change-columns

Comment: @lptr thanks for sharing related posts, but they do not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS` consists of a byte array that can be grouped into groups of 4 bytes. The more columns were changed, the longer the byte array will be, thus the more groups you can make. The first byte of each group represents an ID of a column that was changed. In all of my tests, the other 3 bytes of each group were empty (0). I assume these bytes will be used when you have a column ID larger than 255. It seems the order in which columns were changed determines the order in which they appear in the byte array. Also, the first group of 4 bytes will always be empty (0), I'm not sure why.

To use this in application code, all you need to do is get a mapping for each column name and it's respective column ID. The previous paragraph should explain how to use `SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS` to determine which column ID appears in the byte array.

C# example:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetColumnIdsInMask(byte[] columns)
{
    // TODO: deal with column IDs larger than 255
    for (var i = 4; i < columns.Length; i += 4)
    {
        yield return columns[i];
    }
}

public static bool IsColumnInMask(int columnId, byte[] columns)
{
    return GetColumnIdsInMask(columns).Any(x => x == columnId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely within SQL by using a recursive cte to split up the bytes, then reversing them and casting eventually to an integer value. <s>I have only tested up to column id ~ 20 since I only have narrow tables. I am assuming that values above 255 would work with the same logic</s>.

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'Customer'
DECLARE @ColMask varbinary(4100) = 0x000000000200000004000000;

WITH buckets AS (
    SELECT 1 a,1 b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a + 1, a*4+1 FROM buckets
    WHERE a < LEN(@ColMask)/4
)
SELECT a, CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@ColMask,b,4)) AS varbinary(4)) AS int) ChangedColId,c.name ColumnName
FROM buckets b
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND c.column_id = CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@ColMask,b,4)) AS varbinary(4)) AS int)
```

I have tested with column_ids of values 3,256,258,512 and 519 to verify that the bytes are in the right order, and it works fine.

Disclaimer that the MS documentation does say not to do this directly. It definitely works though.